# How to override setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, three.js

This is part of a larger Three.js project but basically what I am trying to do is display a div for 5 seconds and then making it disappear based on user interaction. However, if the user triggers the interaction before the 5 seconds are up, the current div must disappear to be replaced by a new div and stay for 5 seconds. I am using jQuery for DOM interaction
Here is my code:

```
let lastdiv = 1;
function displayState(text){
    if ($("#temp"+String(lastdiv))){
        $("#temp"+String(lastdiv)).remove();
    }
    lastdiv += 1
    body.append('<div id = "temp' + String(lastdiv) +'" class = "state">' + text + '</div>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($("#temp"+String(lastdiv))){
            $("#temp"+String(lastdiv)).remove();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Currently what happens is that the div shows up for 5 seconds. If there is no further interaction it disappears. However, if there is another interaction within that 5 seconds, the new div does show up but it disappears in 5 seconds since the previous div was displayed i.e. if I trigger the interaction 2 seconds after div1 is displayed, div2 will replace div1 but will disappear after 3 seconds.

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the timeout and cancel it.

```js
const body = $("body");
let lastdiv = 1;
let timer = null;

function hideElement() {
  if (timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#temp"+ lastdiv).remove();
    timer = null;
  }
}

function displayState(text){
    hideElement();
    lastdiv += 1
    body.append('<div id = "temp' + lastdiv +'" class = "state">' + text + '</div>');
    timer = setTimeout(hideElement, 5000);
}


displayState("aaa");

window.setTimeout(() => displayState("bbb"), 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: omg thank you so much. Wish I could upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Store the returned value of `setTimeout` in a variable and call [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel it.

Demo:

```js
var a = setTimeout(function() {
  one.style.display = "none";
}, 5000);
one.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(a);
  this.style.display = "none";
  two.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    two.style.display = "none";
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
#two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">This div will disappear in 5 seconds unless you click it</div>
<div id="two">This div will disappear in 5 seconds</div>
```